# How I can solve FunCaptcha/RotateCaptcha using AntiCaptcha?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, captcha

I am using following code to add anti-captcha chrome plugin with my selenium script. I am able to solve goolge reCAPTCHA V2 but I could not figure out how can I solve RotateCaptcha/FunCaptcha with this plugin.

```
executable_path = "C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(r'D:\anticaptcha.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

[image: RotateCaptcha/FunCaptcha]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The best solution in this case is put a delay longer than usual. When the scraper encounter that captcha, solve it manually and when you are done then you can find the rest working as you want. Sometimes it may break cause within that time you may not be able to solve that captcha. That's it.

Comment: Adding delay does not work for my target website, that's why I am looking for paid solution to resolve FunCaptcha.

Comment: Did you solve the captcha manually after adding a delay before browser throws timeout exception?

Comment: Yes, but captcha occurs frequently. I cannot manually solve it everytime, so want it to automate using Anti-Captcha API, this service has real humans, they solve the captcha and return the result.

Comment: Oh i see!! What i told you is for the sites in which captcha appears once.

Comment: No problem, I got that.

Comment: @Naeem did you find a solution? I've been banging my head for hours and cannot think of a solution.

Comment: @KostasMouratidis I did not find any solution.

Comment: Breaking captchas is a malicious act used by hackers to make the experience of people on the web worse.  Let's not support it.

Answer (score 1):

They have added a whole article about how to use this extension with Selenium.
[Solve captcha in Selenium.](https://antcpt.com/eng/information/recaptcha-2-selenium.html)
Also they described a funcaptcha thing.
[FunCaptcha solving.](https://antcpt.com/eng/information/how-to-use.html#funcaptcha)
Hope it will be helpful. I used Selenium and the extension for solving the Recaptcha only.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible unless you use human.
I know services that called https://2captcha.com/ or like that that gives you 
an API to solve the captcha. 
they send it to someone that response you with the solution

Comment: Yes, I agree. Anti-captcha also provides an API and send captcha to a human to solve that. I used 2catpcha API and successfully resolve normal captcha and reCaptcha V2 but could not resolve Funcaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

it's because funcaptcha sets a delay of 60 seconds, if the captcha is not solved in that time frame, it will fail. and 2captcha is too slow